# difference between viewcontrollers in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

What is the difference between different View Controllers [like, NavigationViewController, Table ViewController,TabViewController etc...] in iPhone? is the difference only is display format? or also in handling the different views on it??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They control different views.
So a UIViewController controls a UIView. A UITableViewController contols a UITableView etc.